# How to change a single users details in Mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

Hey i need to change a users info but only one users info so for instance.

```
id    username     password      Intro
1       Ryan         ****          1
```

I need to change only the Intro part?
i hope this will be changed when the user goes through the intro and then goes to a page where the users Intro will change to 2 to mean yes he has gone through the intro..

and also if it helps my database name is users

Comment: What do you have so far? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 2):

Send an SQL query like:

```
update users set Intro=2 where id=1;
```

Answer (score 2):

This?

```
UPDATE users SET intro = 1 WHERE id = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your user table has primary key id, below code will give u an idea.

```
<?php
$server = ''; // server where your db is hosted
$username = ''; //username of the database
$password = ''; //password of the database
$dbname = ''; //database name of the server
$id = ''; //id of the user you want to change the intro flag of

$vlink = mysql_connect($server,$username,$password);
$dbselect = mysql_select_db($dbname);

//assuming the user already has a row in the table...
$query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user where id = "'. $id . '" and intro = 1';

$result = mysql_query($query,$vlink);

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
    echo 'User has already been through intro';
else
{
    $query = 'UPDATE users SET intro = 2 WHERE id = ' . $id;

    $result = mysql_query($query,$vlink);
    if($result)
        echo 'Success';
    else
        echo 'Failed...!';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE users SET Intro = 2 WHERE id = 'yyy'
```

You need to set yyy to the ID of the logged in user

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$id = (int) $id;
mysql_query("update users set intro = 2 where users.userid = $id;");
```

It's probably worth running through some MySQL tutorials to give you some of the basics.